# Why does Symfony2 replace PHPSESSID upon login?

Tags: php, http, symfony

My Symfony2 application replaces my `PHPSESSID` cookie when it logs me in. Is this expected behavior? It makes no sense to me... why not just keep the same `PHPSESSID`?

Here's a little more detail.

To log in to my application, I *must* first make a request to a URL that hits my app:

```
$ telnet myapp 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: myapp
```

I'm redirected to another URL (`/login`) and given a `PHPSESSID` cookie. Fine. Then I `POST` to `/login_check` something like `_username=blah&_password=blah`, and whether or not I provide proper credentials, I'm sent a different `PHPSESSID` cookie.

Seems like most anything works for this first request, but I must make *some* request (I can't just `POST` to `/login_check` and be logged in). Is this expected behavior?

Not sure if it matters, but I'm using FOSUserBundle.

I guess I should mention that none of this matters until I put my application on two webservers behind a load balancer, and tell the load balancer to use stickiness based on `PHPSESSID`. As you might imagine, the `PHPSESSID` replacement behavior prevents login from working if a client happens to bounce to the other webserver.

Possible duplicate: [Symfony2: login does not work on first try after clearing cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121769/symfony2-login-does-not-work-on-first-try-after-clearing-cookies)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is to prevent [session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation). I would advise another cookie then the session one for loadbalancing.

Comment: Will you elaborate? What might be a better option? Session fixation (cookie hijacking?) is probably irrelevant in our environment because the load balancer only accepts HTTPS traffic (it decrypts then re-encrypts for the webservers). Unless a PHPSESSID ended up on a query string.

Comment: Wait what? You want me to elaborate even _more_ then that wiki page? Well, yes, people misconfigure browsers all the time (accept a cookie for _your_ domain from _another evil domain_, get tricked into posting forms to your domain from other sites, click on links with 'weird' values in the url. Trust me on this one: you really want to take some precautions to prevent it. However: if you insist on using the session cookie as an identifier, you could always generate an id yourself that would end up on the same server and feed it to `session_id`.

Comment: Alright buddy, take it easy. :) That is a helpful wiki page, thank you! Here's the kind of elaboration I had in mind: (1) see if the load balancer can be configured differently, (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801916/ssl-and-session-hijacking-fixation .

Turns out the load balancer (Amazon Elastic Load Balancer) provides a [session] cookie for stickiness, and this appears to work fine.

Comment: Oh, no offense taken or intended, sorry if I came across as blunt. I just assumed that the loadbalancer being capable of using (and most loadbalancers: generating) another cookie  was a given rather then a question, and the wiki page _did_ state HTTPS was little help :P Glad it works!

Answer (score 1):

This can be a bug. For symfony2.0 if you try to read something from session or even try to get a session identifier when SessionListener was not invoked yet you will notice that the new session is started with another PHPSESSID.

This also can be related to locale support, here is my issue for this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3662